# change Jquery variable in if else statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

**---Original code----**

```
$(function () {

    var options = {
    xaxis: { mode: "time", tickLength: 5 },
    selection: { mode: "x" },
    crosshair: { mode: "x" }
    };

 });
```

I want **crosshair: { mode: "x" }** to be inside of options variable when **rlt=true**.

Following is my code, but it's not correct.Is there anyone can point error out?

Thanks!

```
$(function () {
    var rlt = true;
    var options;
    if(rlt){
        options = {
        xaxis: { mode: "time", tickLength: 5 },
        selection: { mode: "x" },
        crosshair: { mode: "x" }
        };
    }else{
        options = {
        xaxis: { mode: "time", tickLength: 5 },
        selection: { mode: "x" }
        };  

    }
 });
```

Comment: Where are you checking the values in your options variable?

Comment: works for me: [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6hcG/);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

works for me, but you can write it this way:

```
var rlt = true;
var options = {
    xaxis: { mode: "time", tickLength: 5 },
    selection: { mode: "x" }
    };  

if (rlt) options.crosshair = { mode: "x" }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have works if you are checking `options.crosshair.mode` inside the `$(function () {}`
where the variable is scoped.